# Django's syncdb is inserting duplicated entries in auth_permission table

Tags: django, django-syncdb, django-fixtures

I have created my models in django and run `manage.py syncdb`

Everything was ok, until I added a new model in an existing app. When I run `syncdb` again, duplicated entries were inserted in `auth_parmission` table. Even for entry log from "admin" app.

I made a test to remove the new model, drop the database, create an empty one and run `syncdb`. This loaded my initial data from an existing fixture.

When I run "syncdb" again (without adding any new model), the same thing happened: duplicated entries were inserted in `auth_permission` table.

Any explanation of what's happening and how to avoid those duplicated entries?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely your initial data fixture includes entries from `auth_permission`. Django creates these initially during syncdb and then runs the fixtures. Your fixture then creates them again.

If you're running Django 1.3+, you can use `--exclude auth` with the `dumpdata` management command to create your fixtures. Otherwise, you'll need to either manually list all the apps/models that should be included (so that `auth` won't be by default) or manually edit the fixture afterwards and remove the `auth` entries.